# Change bootstrap order on mobile - 3 different boxes

Tags: html, css, layout, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to realize a pretty weird layout and i'm actually using bootstrap.
I have 3 boxes: A, B and C where `A.height = B.height + C.height`.
On mobile, they should render in the following order:

```
|B|
|A|
|C|
```

While on desktop i need the following layout:

```
|A||B|
| ||C|
```

(Basically A is the left column while B and C are on the right)

I can't figure out how C should be positioned.
Actually i have this code, it is perfect on mobile but on desktop produces the following layout:

```
|A||B|
| |
|C|
```

Code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-md-push-6">B</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-md-push-6">A</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">C</div>
 </div>
```

Otherwise, putting B and C in the same box works great in desktop but produces

```
|B|
|C|
|A|
```

on mobile.

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: you can either use a blank `col-md-6` OR you can add `pull-right` class to your last div which has *C*.

Comment: It aligns C on the right but with vertical empty space between B and C

Comment: Possible structure will be like [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/quuame94)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following structure will fix your problem:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 pull-right">B</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">A</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 pull-right">C</div>
</div>
```

```css
.box-B,
.box-C {
  background: green;
  height: 200px;
}

.box-A {
  background: blue;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 pull-right box-B">B</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 box-A">A</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 box-C pull-right">C</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the best solution so far

Answer (score 0):

Try the C like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-md-push-6">B</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-md-push-6">A</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 coll-md-offset-6">C</div>
 </div>
```

OR:

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-md-push-6">B</div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-md-push-6">A</div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 pull-right">C</div>
     </div>
```

To change their view in phones or tablets you can use the implemented classes for it for example:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-6">
<p></p>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-6">
<p></p>
</div>
```

Like this in laptops, desktop you will see full width and in phone you will see both divs aligned in one row.

You can allso use col-xs-offset-* to move the div positions but you gotta make shure that you have space. 
For Example:
--- THIS IS WRONG --- Because you have only 12 cols and you are setting 2 + 2 offsets so that means you need total of 16 cols.

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-2">
    <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-2">
    <p></p>
    </div>
```

--- THE RIGHT WAY ---

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-2">
    <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-2">
    <p></p>
    </div>
```

The classes in bootstrap are:

lg - desktop
md - laptop
sm - small devices (tablets)
xs - extra small devices (phones)

together with them you can use `col-**-offset-**` or `col-**-hidden` or `col-**- visible`
But once again if you are going to use offset make sure you are not going above 12 cols

Hope this will help you!

Answer (score 0):

using rows and pull-right you can get the effect you're looking for:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-md-push-6 pull-right">B</div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-md-push-6 pull-right">A</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 pull-right">C</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

that should do the trick.